# How can I compile this very big, but boring C source?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

The central function in my code looks like this (everything else is vanilla input and output):

```c
const int n = 40000;

double * foo (double const * const x)
{
    double * y = malloc (n*sizeof(double));

    y[0] = x[0] + (0.2*x[1]*x[0] - x[2]*x[2]);
    y[1] = x[1] + (0.2*x[1]*x[0] - x[2]*x[2]);
    // …
    // 39997 lines of similar code
    // that cannot be simplified to fewer lines
    // …
    y[40000] = 0.5*x[40000] - x[12345] + 5*x[0];

    return y;
}
```

Assume for the purpose of this question that hard-coding these 40000 lines like this (or very similar) is really necessary. All these lines only contain basic arithmetic operations with fixed numbers and entries of `x` (forty per line on average); no functions are called. The total size of the source is 14 MB.

When trying to compile this code I face an extensive memory usage by the compiler. I could get Clang to compile it with `-O0` (which takes only 20 s), but I failed with the GCC (even with `-O0`) or with `-O1`.

While there is little that can be optimised on the code side or on a global scale (i.e., by computing the individual lines in another order), I am confident that a compiler will find some things to optimise on a local scale (e.g., calculating the bracketed term needed to calculate `y[0]` and `y[1]`).

My questions are thus:

- Are there some compiler flags that activate only optimisations that do not require much additional memory?
- Are there some other ways to make the compiler handle this source better (without losing more speed than gained through optimisation)?

Comment: Note: Any reason you make `x` `const`, but not the array it points to?

Comment: break it into 4 files of 10000 lines each?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much memory does your computer (that's hosting gcc/clang) have?

Comment: @Foon: In one case, the compiler used all of my 4 GB of RAM and almost all of another 8 GB of swap.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on how complicated each expression is?  I wrote a python script to generate samples that looked similar to what you included... my source is "only" 2.7 MB and compiling with gcc -O2 "only" takes 4 minutes (compiling with gcc, no O flags specified only took 20.7 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192494/lee-aniel-crocker) by Lee Daniel Crocker solved the problem:

> I suspect the limit you're running into is the size of the structures needed for a single stack frame/block/function. Try breaking it up into, say, 100 functions of 400 lines each and see if that does better.

When using functions of 100 lines each (and calling all of them in a row), I obtained a program that I could compile with `-O2` without any problem.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, given the original question contained the following statement: Assume for the purpose of this question that hard-coding these 40000 lines like this (or very similar) is really necessary. All these lines only contain basic arithmetic operations with fixed numbers and entries of x (forty per line on average); no functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add swap space](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/) as much as required to get the compiler to compile the code with optimizations enabled. Using this technique, the compilation process will become much slower. However, the amount of memory available to the compiler would be limited only by the size of the virtual address space. Another less convenient option is to install more RAM. Also make sure that the process in which the compiler is running doesn't have limits on the amount of memory it can allocate. Regarding compiler flags, I don't think there are flags that you can use to directly control the memory usage of the compiler and let the compiler adjust itself to the specified limit.

Answer (score -1):

Write it in assembly.

I assume you have a tool that is generating this C file. Why not have it spit out assembly code instead?

Comment: Apart from having to learn assembly, this would probably not bring any advantage optimisation-wise.

Comment: Perhaps you could have clang generate the assembly for you and perform the optimizations, and then link it with the rest of your project that uses GCC.

Comment: Writing custom assembly (if done correctly) will bring huge advantages optimization-wise.

Comment: @user3386109: Only **if** done correctly. And this is where 99.9% of all "optimization evangelists" severely overestimate their abilities.

Comment: @user3386109: Sure, I’ll optimise megabytes of Assembly by hand.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That's not what I said (or at least not what I meant). I was merely agreeing with Doug that the tool should skip C, and go right to assembly.